# Can sshd restrict client tunnel endpoints to localhost?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, sshd

Normally an ssh client can request TCP forwarding using the `-L` command line option. The server can disable this completely using `AllowTcpForwarding no`. If enabled, the client can request to connect the endpoint to a remote machine other than the sshd server using *host* in `-L port:host:hostport`. Is there a way to configure sshd to limit the destination forwarding address to `localhost` (ie. the sshd server machine itself)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A secure default for an OpenSSH installation will have **GatewayPorts** set to **no**. This is precisely that restriction.

***edit***

See the **PermitOpen** directive:

> Specifies the destinations to which TCP port forwarding is permitted.  The forwarding specification must be one of the following forms:
>
> ```
>               PermitOpen host:port
>               PermitOpen IPv4_addr:port
>               PermitOpen [IPv6_addr]:port
> ```
>
> Multiple forwards may be specified by separating them with whitespace.  An argument of “any” can be used to remove all restrictions and permit any forwarding requests.  By default all port forwarding requests are permitted.

Comment: The `GatewayPorts` applies to ports forwarded *for* the client, that is, with the client `-R` option. I'm looking for a restriction on the *destination* addresses when using `-L`.

Comment: It works both for -R and -L, but I see what you mean now, you want to restrict the _origin_ of a forward to a localhost. That's trickier. Gatewayports restricts the _destination_ .

Comment: I already have `GatewaysPorts no` in my `sshd_config`. I can use `ssh -L 1234:anotherhost:1234 server` to set up a tunnel to `anotherhost`. What I want is to allow `ssh -L 1234:localhost:1234 server` but *disallow* `ssh -L 1234:anotherhost:1234 server`.

Comment: Thank you, `PermitOpen` is the option I was looking for! Not sure how I missed that in the man page.

Comment: > _It works both for -R and -L_.

`GatewayPorts` in `~/.ssh/config` sets the policy for `-L`.
`GatewayPorts` in remote host's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` sets the policy for `-R`.